# How to get `radiotype` in Android needed for The Google Maps Geolocation API to find a location using cell tower?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, cellid

I am trying to find user location using **[The Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#body)**. While using this API I need to pass **radiotype** in JSON request body to get the more accurate location from the cell tower. Supported values for **radiotype** are `lte, gsm, cdma, and wcdma.`

Kindly help me in finding **radiotype** in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the following:

```
NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
int type = info.getType(); // wifi or radio
int subType = info.getSubType(); // which is what u want
String radioType = null;
```

you can switch over them like so to look for types you are interested in

```
switch(subType){
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
        radioType = "cdma"
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GSM:
        radioType = "gsm"
        break;
    //more checks you are interested in ie
    //case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_***
}
```

Comment: In some cases people using Reliance Jio SIM card which supports only `lte`   type. How can I get such radio type? How to get `wcdma` radio type?

Comment: Man, please start thinking yourself! Its a crucial programming skill. But for the sake of argument look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html and see a plethora of other TelephonyManager constants

Comment: @NikhilPawar If this answer solved your problem remember to mark it as accepted for fellow devs who got the same problem. Also a high accepted rate might improve willingness by other devs to answer your questions